# "Not in a loop " error in inno setup

Tags: compiler-errors, installation, inno-setup

I am creating an installer using inno setup. 
The code snippet is as follows :

```
function legacy_check(): Boolean;
begin
  // some code
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
continue:Boolean;
oldVersion: String;
begin                                  
   continue:=legacy_check();
   if not continue then 
     Result:=False;
   else
     // some other code
end;
```

here I am getting the error as ""Not in a loop " at line **continue:=legacy_check();**. 
Can anyoone tell what this error is for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Continue` is in Pascal based languages a reserved word, a procedure used in loops to jump to the end of the current repetitive statement. So, you will have to choose a different name for your variable. For instance Delphi (Delphi because it's close to Inno Setup Pascal Script and has online reference) reference describes [`Continue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Continue) like this (emphasized by me):

> Allows the flow of control to proceed to the next iteration of for,
>   while, or repeat statements. In Delphi code, the Continue procedure
>   causes the flow of control to proceed to the next iteration of the
>   enclosing for, while, or repeat statement.
>   **The compiler reports an error if a call to Continue is not enclosed by a for, while, or repeat statement.**